# java code to get Radio Button label from database column entries in zk framework

Tags: java, dynamic, radio-button, zk

I need to generate the radio button in the zk framework according to database column entries and labelling those radio buttons based on the particular column values. Now I am hardcoding the radio button label values. However these values should be taken from the database column entries. In an arraylist "name" I have taken all the values in column. How can assign these to the radio button labels? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite simple, if you use the MVC pattern with a Java class as a controller have a look at the following example:

```
ArrayList<String> columnEntries = new ArrayList<String>();

//populate the array list here, and then...

Radiogroup radiogroup = new Radiogroup();

for(String entry: columnEntries){
 radiogroup.appendItem(entry, entry);
}
```

The `radiogroup.appendItem(entry, entry);` adds automatically a radio button to the specified radiogroup. If you want that the radio button should contain a different value than its label, change the second parameter from `entry` to your desired value.

Comment: Thanks Anto. Have tried as you said. Control is going inside the for each loop. but radio button is not getting aligned in UI. How can do the alignment of radio button in UI. And also now i wrote this inside onCreate() function. Please find my code attached
public void onCreate() {
        ArrayList csvPath = dbcon.getCsvPath();
        ArrayList<String> name = dbcon.getName();
        Radiogroup radiogroup = new Radiogroup();
        for(String entry: name){
          radiogroup.appendItem(entry, entry);
          System.out.println("*********Generating radio button*********");
         }
 }

Comment: Print statement given output as *********Generating radio button*******<Radiogroup null> ten times(since 10 values are there in database it printed for 10 times). Please advice me how to proceed further

Comment: Have resolved my issue. solution used: radiogroup.setVisible(true);

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, I forgot to call the setVisible() method, my apology. You can vote up my answer if you like :-)

Comment: Hi Anto. 
for(String entry: name){
          radio.appendItem(entry, entry);
         }
        radio.setVisible(true);
in ma login.zul
<radiogroup id="radio"></radiogroup>
here how can i make a radio button by default selected?
Please reply me.

Comment: Yes if it is not displayed initially

Comment: Hi Anto. I have Clicked on the Vote tab(seeing above). If it is not the correct method for voting pls let me know. I really want to vote for your answer

Comment: Hi, you should vote up my answer (if you have found it useful of course), just above the green tick :-)

Comment: I just tried. But it shows requires 15 reputation :(

Comment: Hi Anto. How can i arrange this radio buttons one by one. i mean vertically align one at a line. please help me

Comment: Use a vlayout in the zul file and then place the radiogroup inside

Comment: in zul file given like this
<cell>
<vlayout>
<radiogroup id="radio"></radiogroup>
</vlayout>
</cell>
but the radiogroup doesnt have any impact on its alignment

Comment: 1) Use the setRadiogroup(java.lang.String radiogroupId) method to add a radio button to a radio group. 2) If you want to insert radio buttons dynamically in a vlayout, add an id to the vlayout component (for example <vlayout id='myVlayout'>) in the zul file and then try to insert in the controller class the radio button in the vlayout by calling a method from the VLayout class API, i.e.: insertBefore() or appendChild() or appendItem()

Comment: in zul file
<cell> <vlayout> <radiogroup id="radio"></radiogroup> </vlayout> </cell> 
in java controller
private Radiogroup radio = null ;
for(String entry : role) {
radio.appendItem(entry, entry) ;}
radio.setVisible(true) ; 
this is what i have done. by this am getting all the radio buttons in a single line. but i have to show it in vertical alignment. one at a line